# Using window.location to _blank window in JavaScript function

Tags: javascript, html, redirect, window

I'm struggling to open a new window with a redirect based on and onclick function of a link. Any ideas where I am going wrong?

The reason for the function is to mask our affiliate urls, track the click by sending Google Analytics and take the user to a new page with the affiliate link.

At present what is happening is when clicked the click is tracked but then the affiliate link loads in same window and a new window.

**JS Function;**

```
 $(function()
        {
            /**
             * Affiliate Link Click Listener
             * ---
             * 1. prevent the default behaviour.
             * 2. Grab the affiliate url.
             * 3. run google tracking code.
             * 4. redirect the user.
             **/
            $('.affiliate-link').on('click', function(e){

                // Prevent default behaviour
                e.preventDefault();

                // Get the affiliate link
                var affiliate_link = $(this).attr('data-link');

                console.log(affiliate_link);

                // Call our google tracking function
                trackOutboundLink(affiliate_link);

                // Do the redirect
                window.open(affiliate_link, '_blank');
            });
        });

/**
     * Function that tracks a click on an outbound link in Analytics
     * This function takes a valid URL string as an argument, and uses that URL string
     * as the event label. Setting the transport method to 'beacon' lets the hit be sent
     * using 'navigator.sendBeacon' in browser that support it.
     */
    var trackOutboundLink = function(url) {
        ga('send', 'event', 'outbound', 'click', url, {
            'transport': 'beacon',
            'hitCallback': function(){document.location = url;}
        });
    }
```

Link;

```
<a class="apply-btn affiliate-link" href="" data-link="<?= $product['tracking_link']?>" target="_blank">SEE DEAL &raquo;</a>
```

I originally had `window.location.href = affiliate_link;` to do the redirect but a few searches revealed it wasn't possible to target a blank window.

Comment: What happens when you run it? What gets logged? What errors are reported?

Comment: There are no errors or logs - it works in as far as taking the user to the linked site. It opens the link but in the same window - I want it to keep the user on the existing page but open a new window with the link value.

Comment: No logs? So it doesn't output anything for `console.log(affiliate_link);`?

Comment: What do you expect `'hitCallback': function(){document.location = url;}` to do?

Comment: Try adding `window.alert("test");` at different places in your code, to see what parts get executed

Comment: Hit callback is part of Google analytics code to track outbound links. It has not been altered but I want to trigger that function only after our functions have set the link (affiliate_link) to track (and send to GA).

Answer (score -1):

```
 $(function()
        {
            /**
             * Affiliate Link Click Listener
             * ---
             * 1. prevent the default behaviour.
             * 2. Grab the affiliate url.
             * 3. run google tracking code.
             * 4. redirect the user.
             **/
            $('.affiliate-link').on('click', function(e){

                // Prevent default behaviour
                e.preventDefault();

                // Get the affiliate link
                var affiliate_link = $(this).attr('data-link');

                console.log(affiliate_link);

                // Call our google tracking function
               // trackOutboundLink(affiliate_link);

                // Do the redirect
                window.open(affiliate_link, '_blank');
            });
        });
```

//Error in this method trackOutboundLink(affiliate_link); trackOutboundLink is undefiend when me comment this line your code run

Comment: Did you set it in a link like my example shows? `<a class="apply-btn affiliate-link" href="" data-link="<?= $product['tracking_link']?>" target="_blank">SEE DEAL &raquo;</a>`

Comment: The trackoutboundlink  relates to a Goggle Analytics outbound link tracking function - i've updated the main code in my question above.

Comment: what is jquery version you used ?

Comment: Using jquery 2.1.1